# Drawing graphics with paintComponent with color as parameter

Tags: java, swing, graphics, colors, paintcomponent

I have to draw two circles many times, each time with a different pair of colors. So I'd like to pass the colors as arguments to the paintComponent method. But if I do so, the method of the super class JPanel won't be overriden. What should I do? Here's my code:

```
public class Test extends JPanel{

    Ellipse2D oval;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(137, 0, 40, 40);
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);    //color I want to pass as argument
        g2.fill(oval);

        oval = new Ellipse2D.Double(420, 0, 40, 40);
        g2.setPaint(Color.red);    //color I want to pass as argument
        g2.fill(oval);
    }
}
```

I want to pass the colors when calling the constructor:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    Test t1, t2;

    public MyFrame(){
        //setSize, setTitle...

        t1 = new Test();  // would pass the colors in here
        t2 = new Test();  // would pass the colors in here

        add(t1);
        add(t2);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about store two colors as variables in Test. And then via constructor to set the color.

Comment: By the way, you might want to save the initial color of the Graphics object, then change it to what you want, and finally reset it when you are done. Just a habit I have to not be surprised by the colors that are drawn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the colors in the constructor and save them in a class member variable. Then over write paint component to use those colors to draw your circle

so in the Test class add this code

```
private java.awt.Color insideColor;
private java.awt. Color outsideColor;

public class Test (java.awt.Color inside, java.awt.Color outside){
    this.insideColor = inside;
    this.outsideColor = outside; 
}
```